# How can I convert a .png image to .pdf with OCR text?

Tags: pdf, conversion, png, ocr, document-scanning

I have a .png file that is a screenshot of an article I found online. I would like a PDF version of it, with all the text selectable.

Are there any apps or tools that do that?

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Acrobat is the easiest way, though not necessarily the cheapest program. On the Mac, PDFPen is one alternative that can edit PDFs and OCR them. They also make an iOS app that should do what you need. Nuance makes other alternative PDF/OCR software such as Omnipage that can do the same on Windows.

Another option that costs nothing: reopen the article in Chrome and choose "Save as PDF..." when printing instead of taking a screenshot.